# Have a class send data to an engine which calls another class

Tags: ruby

I'm working through Rails the Hardway and am up to exercise 45 which involves making a text adventure where each room is it's own class and there is an engine class that routes you from one class to another. Additionally, there must be several files.

The code that I'm currently using will allow me to use the engine outside of a class or method but if I call the Engine class from a third class I received a message that says Falcon (the classname) is unitialized.

I'm basing the game on Star Wars and am eminently thankful for any help you can offer - even if it means approaching the problem a different way.

runner.rb:

```
    module Motor
      def self.runner(class_to_use, method_to_use = nil) 
        if method_to_use.nil? == false 
          room = Object.const_get(class_to_use).new
          next_room.method(method_to_use).call()
        else
          room = Object.const_get(class_to_use).new
          puts room
        end
      end  
    end
```

map.rb 
        require_relative 'runner'
        require_relative 'characters'

```
    class Falcon

      def luke
        puts "It works!"
      end

      def obi_wan
        puts "this is just a test"
      end
    end
```

characters.rb

```
    class Characters

      include Motor

      puts "You can play as Luke Skywalker or Obi-wan Kenobi"
      puts "Which would you like?"
      character = gets.chomp()

        if character == "Luke Skywalker"
          puts "The Force is strong with this one."
          Motor.runner(:Falcon, :luke)
        elsif character == "Obi Wan Kenobi"
          puts "It's been a long time old man."
          Motor.runner(:Falcon, :obi_wan)
        else 
          puts "I have no idea what you're saying."
        end
     end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably not going to the right direction. You don't need this `Motor` module and you should not have the `puts` and `get` call inside of the `Character` class. Not sure how much do you know about programming, but the solution for this includes some basic data structures knowledge, as in building a linked list of rooms (so that each room knows which one is the next) and recursion to navigate on this list.

First create a `Room` base class:

```
class Room 
    attr_accessor :description, :next_room

    def initialize( description, next_room )
        @description = description
        @next_room = next_room
    end 

end
```

Then a character:

```
class Character 
    attr_accessor :title

    def initialize( title )
        @title = title
    end 

end
```

Then you would build the map:

```
first_room = Room.new( 'Some room', Room.new( 'Golden Room', Room.new( 'Black room', nil ) ) )
```

And then you should create another class that will read from the command line and move the `Character` between the rooms.

Answer (score 0):

characters.rb

```
require 'map.rb'
```